# Как использовать правила языка для «строк состояний» интерфейса пользователя?

Tags: орфография

Какие правила русского языка следует использовать при создании интерфейса пользователя для «неполных строк», то есть таких строк, которые не являются законченными предложениями.

Например, если участники сообщества закрывают вопрос, под вопросом появляется следующий текст

> **закрыт** по причине того, что необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ участниками Oceinic, Aries, Aslan Kussein, ermak0ff, Qwertiy 16 окт '15 в 7:07

Текст начинается со строчной буквы и не имеет точки в конце. Правильно ли это? Как следует поступать с инструментами модерации (ссылки «править», «закрыть» и т. д.)?

Comment: "Неполные строки" тут слитно.

Comment: @behemothus Спасибо! Поправил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот текст представляет собой вполне законченное предложение, ничего неполного в нем нет. Грамматически представляет собой полное (двусоставное) предложение, с опущенным (подразумеваемым) подлежащим.

Желательно (если движок позволяет) оформлять по общим правилам орфографии и пунктуации. Заглавная в начале, точка в конце.

> **Закрыт** по причине того, что необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ участниками Oceinic, Aries, Aslan Kussein, ermak0ff, Qwertiy 16 окт '15 в 7:07.

Впрочем, даже если предложение неполное, на него распространяются те же самые правила о заглавной и точке. Единственные исключения - заголовки всех уровней а также правила оформления цитат и прямой речи - во всех этих случаях по современным правила точка в конце не ставится (или заменяется на нужный знак).

С другой стороны я бы поменял порядок.

> **Закрыт** 16 окт '15 в 7:07 участниками Oceinic, Aries, Aslan Kussein, ermak0ff, Qwertiy по причине необходимости переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы существовал объективно верный ответ.

Но это уже не так принципиально.

//===============

> Как следует поступать с инструментами модерации (ссылки «править», «закрыть» и т. д.)

Не понял вопроса. А зачем с ними как-то поступать? И о каких ссылках речь?
Тут есть только одна проблема: рекомендуемый способ оформления ссылок (через сноски) глючит на длинных ссылках и на ссылках, содержащих кириллицу. Но к этому давно привыкли. 
А что еще можно делать с ссылками? Править - ну да, ошибочные. Закрывать? Ну можно и закрыть, если ведет куда-то не туда... "Разрешить" еще можно, если она неопределенная...

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, про «заголовки всех уровней» и что делать с «закрыть», «поделиться» и т. д.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky - заголовки - это заглавия книг, журналов, статей, отдельных их разделов, глав, названия фильмов и т. п. Там точки не ставят. Про ссылки - не понял контекста. Написал.

Comment: Ссылки – ссылки под телом сообщения.

Comment: >> *Грамматически представляет собой полное (двусоставное) предложение, с опущенным (подразумеваемым) подлежащим.* Грамматически представляет собой НЕполное предложение, с опущенным (подразумеваемым) подлежащим. Ай-яй-яй.